# .net linq query joins

Tags: c#, linq, many-to-many

I'm having some trouble with my "where" clause in a linq query.
I have the following three tables.

Items {ItemId,Name}

Buckets {BucketId, Name}

ItemsBuckets {Id, BucketId, ItemId}

Items can exist in multiple buckets, which is why I have the ItemsBuckets Table. 
I want to find all the items that have a specific bucket with name containing bucketname.

```
System.Linq.IQueryable<Item> query = context.Items.Include("ItemsBuckets")
                     .Include("ItemsBuckets.Buckets");
query = query.Where(n => n.ItemsBuckets.Buckets.Name.Contains(bucketname));
ObservableCollection<Item> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(query.ToList());
```

my where clause does not work. I get the following error:

```
Error   CS1061  'ICollection<ItemsBuckets>' does not contain a definition for 
'Buckets' and no extension method 'Buckets' accepting a first argument of
 type ICollection<ItemsBuckets> could be found (are you missing a using 
directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I can not figure out a way to approach this. Any ideas?

Comment: Where does `query` come from?  Why are you assigning to `q` twice?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I have edited the code to show where query comes from. In my actual code I have several query = query.Where  statements.

Comment: What error message are you seeing, or what's not working as you expect it to?

Comment: sorry, added the error message

Comment: Try enumerating your first results set (`query`) using `ToList()` and seeing if you can search that result set.  I included some code in my answer below.

Comment: It seems to be complaining that ICollection<ItemsBuckets>'  is an ICollection and therefor does not known about Buckets. Each Item has multiple ItemsBuckets. Each ItemBucket would then have a Bucket. Enumerating the query still leaves me with the same problem.

Comment: thanks @awh112, Fredy's response worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the following?

```
var query = context.Items
                   .Where(i => i.ItemsBuckets.Any(ib => ib.Bucket.Name.Contains(bucketname)));

var items = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enumerate your results by taking your first query and calling `.ToList()`, then use your `Where()` clause on that result set.

```
var q = context.Items.Include("ItemsBuckets").Include("ItemsBuckets.Buckets").ToList();
var results = q.Where(n => n.ItemsBuckets.Buckets.Name.Contains(bucketname));
```

Comment: This is inefficient as you are returning the whole database of ItemsBuckets to code. The filter would be better at the database tier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a property `Buckets of ICollection<ItemBucket>` on `Item`:

```
var query = from item in context.Items
           where item.Buckets.Any(b => b.BucketName == name)
           select item;

return query.ToList();
```